# Recovering accidental edits through ArcGIS Pro Version Changes window?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing, arcgis-pro, versioning

We have a situation with our ArcSDE where features were accidentally deleted inside a version and we would like to recover those changes. We cannot undo edits because they were saved in a previous session, we have reconciled the version once, and we do have backups of the data if that's what it comes down to.

**It seems possible to recover accidental edits through ArcGIS Pro's Version Changes window, but is there a particular workflow that needs to be followed to make replacements stick?**

We know this was not possible in ArcMap, but playing around in Pro suggests that the same functionality we've had for resolving conflicts post-reconcile has been carried over to Version Changes:

[image: Version Changes in Pro]

In this particular situation, we want to replace "Current" (the accidental change that happened in the version) with target (what's shown in DEFAULT). However, when we tell the application to "Replace with Target Version", nothing resolves.

My extensive research has turned up very little so far.

We're running Pro 2.2.4 with Oracle SDE, and our DBA tells me he compresses states twice a week.

Comment: This is a really a very detail-oriented situation that is more appropriate for a Tech Support incident. There are many, many permutations on whether and how the data can be recovered. Keep the relevant backup media out of the reuse poor until this is resolved.

Comment: @Vince good point,  I'm working with ESRI now and will update the question as I learn more.